# Как живет современная школа?

Tags: общие-вопросы, обучение, образование

Наверное, живет она по-разному. И всё-таки: стало ли современное образование лучше и свободнее в нашем новом, свободном обществе? Конечно, особый интерес вызывает преподавание русского языка. К примеру, я не так давно занималась со старшеклассницей, и там педагог очень  неплохо вел литературу (действительно, задания мне казались интересными и творческими), но русский язык давался авторитарно, с элементарными ошибками и полным неприятием всякого инакомыслия. Иногда мне кажется, что грамматика ближе стоит к математике, и педагогу трудно быть на высоте и там и здесь.

Вот несколько забавных школьных выражений из современного словаря: Диктант – это диктатура. Чистое насилие над личностью, когда так быстро диктуют. Русыня нам каждый урок диктует по пять строчек, а проверяет выборочно – это очень нервирует. Русачка сегодня была в ударе – наизусть всего "Онегина" нам прочла. Русский – по определению долбальник, в любой школе.

А вы что знаете и думаете на эту тему?

Comment: София, почему бы Вам действительно не помещать такие вопросы в рубрике "Исследования"? Желающие поговорить на эту тему найдутся. Здесь вопрос-ответ,там рассуждения, обмен опытом. Честно говоря, 4 года в школе не работаю, обсуждать кого-то не хочу и не имею права. А порассказать у всех есть что.Школы разные, учителя разные, обобщать будут потом учёные,теоретики.

Comment: А исследования никто не читает. Я там однажды поместила заметочку, так ее за три дня так никто и не прочитал. Пришлось убрать. И теперь о теме. Если Вам она неинтересна или Вы не имеете право никого обсуждать, то можно просто не участвовать в разговоре.

Answer (score 7):

Роль личности учителя трудно переоценить. Учителя разные, школы разные - поэтому в формате этого форума вопрос кажется слишком объёмным. Я в школе почти 30 лет и учителей знаю очень разных. В большинстве своем это умницы и труженицы; те, кто не любит детей  или предмет, из школы давно ушли.

Я совершенно с Вами согласна, что грамматика ближе к математике. Мы в своей школе долгое время даже такую специализацию практиковали: я, например, русский язык вела, а коллега литературу. Литераторы более эмоциональны, у русоведов лучше развито логическое мышление. Кроме того, специализация облегчает подготовку. В вузе специализация не только по предмету, но и по веку и даже автору. Конечно, это условно  - облегчение. У русоведов больше проверки, у литераторов - чтения.

Про инакомыслие... Я была бы рада, если бы у всех детей было бы это "мыслие", не только инакомыслие, но вообще - потребность думать. Да, есть умницы. Но очень много детей, которым думать не хочется. Вообще. Потому что из дома ушли голодными, и мысли о том, когда прозвенит звонок и можно будет побежать в столовую. Или о том, как объяснить учителю, почему снова не был в школе: нянчился с новорожденным братиком, пока мама решала свои проблемы. (Извините, это у меня сейчас такие проблемы: взяла класс вместо надолго заболевшей коллеги, а они даже без ошибок с доски списывать не могут(=не хотят), не знают элементарных слов - какое тут лингвистическое сочинение или сжатое изложение на слух (экзамен в 9 классе), они к слову "хорошо" задают вопрос что?. Есть умницы, есть и победители олимпиад, есть любящие учиться. Но гораздо больше других. И если приходится иметь дело именно с такими классами, приходится туго. Так что я с вами согласна, пусть будут у детей разные мнения - это замечательно, пусть думают - и ошибаются! - вместе придем к общему мнению. Люблю думающих. Если при этом еще и трудолюбивые... Но как за ограниченное время (если берешь детей ближе к 9 классу) заинтересовать, научить думать и одновременно подготовить к экзамену  - я не знаю.

Answer (score 3):

Школа всегда была и будет *конкретной*.

В советское время у меня был скандал коромыслом с директором школы из-за принуждения детей к покупке марок ОСВОДа. Сегодня учительница моей дочери по Окружающему миру (для этого предмета у нас в первом классе отдельный учитель!) заставляет первоклассников делать **компьютерные презентации**. *Всегда были и будут трусливые идиоты, сваливающие с себя ответственность, отказывающиеся включать мозг в процесс обучения и воспитания*.

Но моя дочь пока что с удовольствием ходит в школу, потому что у неё прекрасная воспитательница в продлёнке (где первоклассники проводят бОльшую часть дня) - разумная, уравновешенная, не мучающая детей глупыми невыполнимыми задачами. *Всегда были и будут люди, которые держат школу на своих плечах*.

Всегда будет редкостной удачей встретить в школе хорошего учителя **русского языка**. Потому что язык СВЕРХсложен, слишком тесно связан с мышлением, с самой сутью человеческой личности. По этому поводу часто вспоминаю фрагмент старого итальянского сериала: *пожилой учитель словесности на допросе у Прокурора; прокурор говорит с укоризной: "Вы меня не помните? я ведь у вас троечником всегда был, а теперь вот глядите, как высоко забрался - Прокурор!" - а учитель в ответ: "Так ведь итальянский язык - это не просто набор грамматических правил, это умение рассуждать. Рассуждай вы меньше, не так бы ещё высоко забрались..."*

Answer (score 0):

В свободном обществе? Свободном от чего, позвольте узнать? От морали? Нравственности? Возможно. Только это не свобода.

Comment: Если обращать внимание на такие детали, на вопрос вообще невозможно будет ответить! :-) Я уж не стал придираться к изумившему меня упоминанию "инакомыслия". Боюсь даже предположить, какие формы может принимать его _подавление_ в школьном курсе русского языка. Ну, например... неужели тиран-учитель запрещает писать "заЕц"?!